# Embedded fonts works for designer but not for application

Tags: wpf, fonts

I am building a wpf application and I wanted to use Open Sans Regular font in my application.

I referred [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) link for embedding font. I added OpenSans Regular.ttf file to resources under project properties.

Then I referred them in my application as mentioned below:

```
<Window x:Class="FontEmbeddingDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" FontFamily="Resources/#Open Sans">
<Window.Resources>
    
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Height="100" Text="This is test text." FontSize="14" FontFamily="Resources/#Open Sans"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

In designer of Visual Studio I can see font changed to open sans but when I run the application it is taking system default font (Arial in my system).

Do let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: I think, you have to add the font file to your project and set its `BuildAction` to Resource.

Comment: It is added as a resource to project. And I think resources are not compiled. They are used as it is.

Comment: @sthotakura: and also I can see in the designer the effect is being applied, but when i build the project and run application in the application window i can't see fonts applied as open sans

Comment: @sthotakura: But you were right, I changed build action to resource. It worked. Thanks a ton :) please post it as answer so i can mark it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) Page:

> When you add fonts as resources to your application, make sure you are
> setting the `<Resource>` element, and not the  element
> in your application's project file. The `<EmbeddedResource>` element for
> the build action is not supported.

So, I guess, you will have to add this font file to your project as you would add any other file and set its `BuildAction` to `Resource` instead of adding the font to the Resources under Project Properties, which will make it as an EmbeddedResource.

**EDIT**

Read [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20190212070319/http://geekswithblogs.net/Martinez/archive/2010/01/29/custom-font-in-wpf-application.aspx) excellent article on how to use custom fonts in a WPF application.

You could also, get this working by way @Sheridan mentioned - which is setting `BuildAction` to `Content`. However, the problem with this approach is you will have loose separate file hanging around along with your binary. Users can potentially change this file, which may cause problems with your app. It is best to use `Resource` as `BuildAction` as the font gets bundled into the assembly.

Comment: Just one small comment to the linked article: if you would like to use the font from a different project, then you might want to add the assembly name to the font location string:
'pack://application:,,,/assemblyName;Resources/#Open Sans'

Comment: But I do have the `BuildAction` of my font file set to `Resource` (and it's still not working)...

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, I believe that the accepted answer to this question may either be incorrect, or misleading. I am using `Font` files in exactly the same way and I have absolutely no need to set their `BuildAction` to `Resource`. My `Font` files have a `BuldAction` set to `Content` and that works just fine. I'm guessing that the accepted answer would only help users that have set their `Font` file to `EmbeddedResource`.

The comment that @sthotakura quoted from the linked MSDN page is merely talking about manually editing the project file, which the question author is not doing. Note that there is no mention of `BuildAction` property in the linked page apart from mentioning that the `EmbeddedResource` value is invalid in this case.

Please try this instead or as well:

Set the `BuildAction` of the `Font` file(s) to `Content`.
Reference the `Font` file like this (with the all important starting slash):

```
FontFamily="/Resources/#Open Sans"
```

I just tried removing the starting slash in my project and the `Font` defaulted to another `Font`, so I'm pretty sure that this will work... all the same, please let me know. I'm more than happy to remove this answer if I am mistaken.

Comment: I understood OP's resource BuildAction is EmbeddedResource since OP mentioned OP added to resources under projec t properties. I suggested him to change to it `Resource`. I know OP can achieve by setting the `BuildAction` to `Content`, but I do not recommend that, as it can leave your font files for potential tampering by users. If you read the MSDN page, it discusses all possible ways to add custom fonts. So, my answer was neither incorrect nor misleading.

Comment: @sthotakura, while I accept that you helped the user fix their problem, I am merely concerned that other users looking for a solution to this problem may not have their `Font` file `BuildAction` set to `EmbeddedResource` and so your answer may not help them... my point is that your solution will only help a user that *does* have their file `BuildAction` set to `EmbeddedResource`. I was looking for a more global solution that would help anybody, but I didn't mean to imply anything by this answer... hopefully you understand that.

Comment: It would have been nice if the question author had come back and confirmed or denied that this solution worked so that future users could have that information too, but it doesn't really matter... they can just read this answer and try it themselves if yours doesn't help. Also @sthotakura, I edited the start of my answer to not sound quite so rude... I don't mean it... I guess I'm just naturally rude.

Comment: Edited my answer and included link to a blog post that disucsses this problem (adding custom fonts) in detail. Thanks :)

Comment: @Sheridan: well I came across this font issue, and I took msdn route. And tried to make fonts as the embedded resource. So I believe answer was according to msdn because i mentioned its reference too. But this discussion really led me to global solution. Making them resource would limit them to one project in solution. Sorry for late action. I was driving. :)

Comment: @sthotakura: Thanks a ton you also. Sorry can't tag two ppl in single comment